# Selenium: Exception on determination of SessionCapabilities (when called from php-webdriver-bindings)

Tags: php, exception, selenium, automated-tests

I am setting up testing with Selenium under PHP using php-webdriver-bindings. Did anybody come across the following problem with the example from the [project home](http://code.google.com/p/php-webdriver-bindings/)?

When executing the example test the *server* throws an ExecutionException. Performing the same steps from Java works without problems. (The steps are probably not so important anyway as the exception occurs on determination of session capabilities, already)

The PHP code:

```
<?php
require_once "phpwebdriver/WebDriver.php";
/*require("phpwebdriver/LocatorStrategy.php");*/ /*already included*/

$webdriver = new WebDriver("localhost", "4444");
$webdriver->connect("firefox");                            
$webdriver->get("http://google.com");
$element = $webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::name, "q");
$element->sendKeys(array("selenium google code" ) );
$element->submit();

$webdriver->close();
?>
```

The Java code:

```
package asdfjkl.selenium.test;

import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class Sel2Test2  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URL url = null;

        try {
            url = new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
                url, DesiredCapabilities.firefox());

        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        element.sendKeys("selenium google code");
        element.submit();

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

The server output on execution of the PHP test (exception thrown):

```
May 29, 2012 11:57:55 AM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a standalone server
11:57:56.537 INFO - Java: Sun Microsystems Inc. 20.0-b11
11:57:56.539 INFO - OS: Linux 2.6.18-308.1.1.el5 i386
11:57:56.554 INFO - v2.21.0, with Core v2.21.0. Built from revision 16552
11:57:57.774 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
11:57:57.775 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
11:57:57.776 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
11:57:57.777 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
11:57:57.777 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
11:58:01.141 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@90cb03
11:58:01.141 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
11:58:01.145 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
11:58:01.145 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@af8358
11:59:57.941 INFO - Executing: [new session: {javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, nativeEvents=false, version=}] at URL: /session)
12:00:11.527 INFO - Done: /session
12:00:11.531 INFO - Executing: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.GetSessionCapabilities@134263a at URL: /session/1338285476985)
12:00:11.531 INFO - Done: /session/1338285476985
12:00:11.532 INFO - WebDriver remote server: Fatal, unhandled exception: /session/1338285476985: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
12:00:11.532 WARN - EXCEPTION
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:603)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doGet(DriverServlet.java:539)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:520)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:428)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.dispatch(ServletHandler.java:677)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:568)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1530)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1482)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:909)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
        at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:357)
        at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:534)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.WebDriverHandler.execute(WebDriverHandler.java:90)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:240)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:597)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.renderer.ForwardResult.render(ForwardResult.java:39)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig$1.call(ResultConfig.java:233)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig$1.call(ResultConfig.java:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:151)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
12:00:11.533 WARN - /wd/hub/session/1338285476985:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.WebDriverHandler.execute(WebDriverHandler.java:90)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:240)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:597)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doGet(DriverServlet.java:539)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:520)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:428)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.dispatch(ServletHandler.java:677)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:568)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1530)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1482)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:909)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
        at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:357)
        at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:534)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.renderer.ForwardResult.render(ForwardResult.java:39)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig$1.call(ResultConfig.java:233)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig$1.call(ResultConfig.java:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:151)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
12:00:11.540 INFO - Executing: [get: http://google.com] at URL: /session/1338285476985/url)
12:00:12.664 INFO - Done: /session/1338285476985/url
12:00:12.666 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.name: q] at URL: /session/1338285476985/element)
12:00:12.956 INFO - Done: /session/1338285476985/element
12:00:12.961 INFO - Executing: [send keys: 0 org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringWebElement@13472277, [selenium google code]] at URL: /session/1338285476985/element/0/value)
12:00:13.096 INFO - Done: /session/1338285476985/element/0/value
12:00:13.097 INFO - Executing: [submit: 0 org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringWebElement@13472277] at URL: /session/1338285476985/element/0/submit)
12:00:13.227 INFO - Done: /session/1338285476985/element/0/submit
12:00:13.228 INFO - Executing: [delete session: 1338285476985] at URL: /session/1338285476985)
12:00:13.304 INFO - Done: /session/1338285476985
```

The server output on execution of the Java test (no exception thrown):

```
May 29, 2012 12:02:26 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a standalone server
12:02:26.682 INFO - Java: Sun Microsystems Inc. 20.0-b11
12:02:26.684 INFO - OS: Linux 2.6.18-308.1.1.el5 i386
12:02:26.695 INFO - v2.21.0, with Core v2.21.0. Built from revision 16552
12:02:26.816 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.   1:4444/wd/hub
12:02:26.818 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
12:02:26.818 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server   /driver]
12:02:26.819 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
12:02:26.819 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
12:02:26.842 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@288051
12:02:26.842 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
12:02:26.846 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
12:02:26.846 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@af8358
12:04:02.749 INFO - Executing: [new session: {platform=ANY, browserName=firefox     version=}] at URL: /session)
12:04:04.910 INFO - Done: /session
12:04:04.949 INFO - Executing: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.GetSes    ionCapabilities@134263a at URL: /session/1338285746744)
12:04:04.950 INFO - Done: /session/1338285746744
12:04:04.991 INFO - Executing: [get: http://www.google.com] at URL: /session/13    8285746744/url)
12:04:05.624 INFO - Done: /session/1338285746744/url
12:04:05.658 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.name: q] at URL: /session/1338    85746744/element)
12:04:05.919 INFO - Done: /session/1338285746744/element
12:04:05.988 INFO - Executing: [send keys: 0 org.openqa.selenium.support.events    EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringWebElement@4175a8c3, [selenium google code]] at    URL: /session/1338285746744/element/0/value)
12:04:06.095 INFO - Done: /session/1338285746744/element/0/value
12:04:06.124 INFO - Executing: [submit: 0 org.openqa.selenium.support.events.Ev    ntFiringWebDriver$EventFiringWebElement@4175a8c3] at URL: /session/133828574674    /element/0/submit)
12:04:06.247 INFO - Done: /session/1338285746744/element/0/submit
12:04:06.274 INFO - Executing: [delete session: 1338285746744] at URL: /session    1338285746744)
12:04:06.346 INFO - Done: /session/1338285746744
```

Has anybody come across this? I know that Selenium does not officially support PHP. But I don't think it should let any connection fail the server like that. I also wonder that apparently nobody noticed although the example code is prominently displayed on the php-webdriver-bindings' home page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey, were you able to resolve this issue? I'm facing the same problem right now and looking for solution.

Answer (score 1):

That is due to incorrect "Accept:" header that is send by PHP WebDriver binding library you use.

On session initialization you need to specify the header: "Accept: application/json"

In order to do that you need to slightly patch your library or upgrade to latest version that already can have this fix.

To apply patch manually - find the line that send initial requests to WebDriver Server:

```
curl_setopt( $this->_curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
```

and change it to:

```
curl_setopt( $this->_curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("application/json;charset=UTF-8", "Accept: application/json"));
```

Error will not occur again anymore.
See more information here:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2091

https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/issues/9#issuecomment-3381300

Comment: Hey, thanks for sharing your solution. However the webdriver binding in my question is not the one from facebook but from another project. The problem might be similar however. Sometime after posting the question I had a look at the requests/responses send when using the php webdriver and the Java library respectively. I did not have the time for a closer look, but in comparison the request in the php setting did not feel correct :(